# Workbox routing for images in subfolders

Tags: javascript, regex, workbox

I am using workbox to manage the caching of my assets, which works great.

I am having 1 or 2 issues with regular expressions when caching my images:

I am trying to cache all images in the images folder & icons subfolder (image of folder structure below)

I have tried the following to try and cache the images:

```
workbox.routing.registerRoute(
  /images\/.(?:png|gif|jpg|jpeg|svg|ico|webp)$/,  //<-- Regexp
  workbox.strategies.cacheFirst({
   cacheName: 'images',
   plugins: [
    new workbox.expiration.Plugin({
      maxEntries: 100,
      maxAgeSeconds: 60 * 60 * 24 * 365
    }),
  ],
 }),
);

//I also tried a regexp on the entire images folder
workbox.routing.registerRoute(
  new RegExp('^/images/'),    //<-- Regexp
  workbox.strategies.cacheFirst({
    cacheName: 'images',
    plugins: [
      new workbox.expiration.Plugin({
        maxEntries: 100,
        maxAgeSeconds: 60 * 60 * 24 * 365
      }),
    ],
  }),
);
```

I included the code samples above to give context to what I am trying to achieve

Any help would be appreciated!

Folder Structure:

[image]

Comment: Not sure about workbox etc.  For the regex maybe: `images\/.*\.(?:png|gif|jpg|jpeg|svg|ico|webp)$`.  See demo: https://regex101.com/r/ASmdxd/1. it's just taking the one `.` and making it `.*` for 'match anything any number of times' and then an actual . with `\.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few different ways that you can define routes in Workbox. While you can pass in a RegExp as the first parameter to `registerRoute()`, like you're doing, you could instead pass in a [`matchCallback` function](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/reference-docs/latest/module-workbox-routing#~matchCallback), which can examine the incoming request and return either a "truthy" or false value depending on whether you want the route to trigger.

There's a [recipe](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/common-recipes#cache_resources_based_on_resource_type) in the Workbox docs for setting up a route based on the `request.destination` value, which for subresources being used as images on your page, will be `'image'`. You could combine that with a check of the `url.pathname` inside of your `matchCallback` if you want to limit your route so that it only matches images within a certain subfolder.

So, taken together, it would look something like:

```
workbox.routing.registerRoute(
  ({request, url}) => request.destination === 'image' &&
                      url.pathname.startsWith('/images'),
  workbox.strategies.cacheFirst({
    cacheName: 'images',
    plugins: [
      new workbox.expiration.Plugin({
        maxEntries: 100,
        maxAgeSeconds: 60 * 60 * 24 * 365
      }),
    ],
  })
);
```